# VBA MS Word Font color

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to read read through a Word document, find any text that is marked in any color other then black and delete it. How to find the text color in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub DeleteNonBlack()
   Dim Wrd As Range

   For Each Wrd In ActiveDocument.Words
    If Wrd.Font.Color<>wdColorBlack and wrd.Font.Color<>wdColorAutomatic Then
      Wrd.Delete
    end if

   Next Wrd

End Sub
```

HTH